# Potential issue with voltage regulator on PCB: output voltage lower than expected

Tags: eaglecad, linear-regulator

## Background

I've designed a simple PCB that, among other things, takes 12V as input, outputs a 12V to an Arduino Mega 12V input, and then—through a linear voltage regulator, and at least in theory—outputs stable 5V to the rest of the components.

## Issue

While the voltage differential across the "stabilizing" output capacitor for the linear voltage regulator is the expected 5V, the other components of the PCB are only getting ~1.7V.

I've included both the schematic and board designs (Autodesk EAGLE) for this project: [Schematics](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qhOyppaiCXNuPaO-WkYUI68ma8AdRxLO/view?usp=sharing), [Board design](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NaGdFsM2q-0nKU3U4B24mcVfuvq6WOdG/view?usp=sharing).

---

Firstly, I'm sorry for not using standard schematic parts. I've added them below: (links deleted due to reputation-limitations)

---

I've incorporated the design guidelines to the best of my abilities. Due to my reputation limitations, I cannot post all of the links required for the schematics. So, as a work-around for the moment, I've made a single google doc with all the needed links and images. Here's the link:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Po5UYqOEr9vQJeOwjLvSAWGIM6KsR-U0fOXidx7J9fg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Bad connection somewhere. Check GND (that cap) to GND (other components) and 5V (cap) to 5V (others). One of them is about 3.3V. You know what to do...

Comment: Please put enough of your schematics directly into your question (screengrabs with no background grid) so that we don't have to follow links to understand the question and so that the question still makes sense when the links die.

Comment: As a tip for your board design, have you heard of ground planes?

Comment: @BrianDrummond thank you for your response. Firstly, and if you don't mind telling me, how did you find out which one had a 3.3V differential based on the schematic? Additionally, I compared the grounds of the "main" input and the "SD" input, and similar compared the Vout of the "main" and the Vout of the "SD." the values are 3.3V and 0, respectively. Would you say the issue is because I did not use a ground plane (as I just have learned about them)?

Comment: @Transistor my apologies—would a picture of the schematics be enough?

Comment: @Doodle it's the first time I hear that—I'll implement it in my next designs. Anything else you'd see wrong with this design that could have added to the problem?

Comment: Brian didn't find it, he is telling you how to find it. IMO, try adding jumpers from the nets that should be connected. It should fix it and you don't have to hunt for bad connections. Whether you actually need to find the specific issue or just bypass it depends on what you want to do with your project.

Comment: @Arian: A screengrab (picture) nicely cropped is great. It makes it easy for your readers to decide if they can contribute an answer.

Comment: I haven't looked at the schematics. Or the PCB. If its your own layout, you may have forgotten to connect part of the ground net to the rest.Otherwise there is a break in one of the ground tracks. Either way, get the tack wire and soldering iron out.

Comment: Firstly, thank you all for your responses. I've learned about ground planes (and power planes) today, and will add them to the next design iteration. I still have one major question—regarding potential faulty connections: beyond the addition of the planes, is there a faulty connection in the design also? I could not find any, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: "I've added a picture of the schematic."  No you didn't, that is the board layout.  File:Export the schematic and post that.

Comment: @CrossRoads my apologies—will do.

Comment: As per the other comments, add a Gnd plane. (draw a Polygon around the board and Name it Gnd. Add to both layers.)  Also, your power traces are very thin. Make them fatter, like 32 mil at least.

Comment: @CrossRoads thank you for your response. Do you also happen to see a faulty connection somewhere?

Comment: Faulty connections are typically in manufacture, not design. Its difficult to design a loose connection or bad solder joint, but it can be pretty easy to manufacture one. Also with regards to your schematic, try to use some standard symbols for things like capacitors, resistors, and diodes. Your schematic is very hard to understand using boxes for everything. You should be using names for nets, not just numbers. `7` and `8` don't mean as much as `LED_SIGNAL` for example.

Comment: @RonBeyer got it, thank you! So in theory, my design should work as expected?

Comment: I honestly can't tell with all the disconnected/disjointed boxes and numbers-as-net-names. I can't tell if your LED's/diodes are backwards, if your capacitors are polarized, any part numbers for your regulator, etc. It's suspicious that you have things like `GND_3`, you should only have one `GND` net...

Comment: My apologies, I'll add them to the original question stem. Will update here once I've added the parts.

Comment: @RonBeyer I've added the parts. Regarding the different GND numbers, I'm sorry for not explaining earlier: I did not want the ground pins of the Arduino Mega to "get involved" in the final PCB, and so I changed their names to that they won't have airwires.

Comment: I find the schematic completely unreadable! Question should be closed.

Comment: "Do you also happen to see a faulty connection somewhere?" Can't tell without looking up each component.  I do see lots of vias that are not needed as pointed out.  Right click on trace segments like the one that ends at D12, and change it from Top to Bottom. Find others like that.

Comment: Got it, thank you! Will redesign and post as a separate thread.

Comment: All of these traces look extremely thin, I hope you're not pushing much current through them.

Answer (score 0):

So.. its hard to even tell from you description and schematic what should be connected, and what isn't connected.

But there are some obvious things we can point out:

1 - Ground planes, as others pointed out.

2 - "Power" traces. Vout goes through so many vias and such a long path of thin traces that any current draw or spike can disrupt your whole circuit.

3 - Your regulator has barely any "bulk" capacitance. Depending on what you are sourcing it and what you are drawing, it might not regulate properly.

4 - <s>Assuming that what I underlined as green below is the output, the Vouts that I underlined in yellow are not connected to it (or to anything besides that resistor)</s>
I just realized those are LED outputs. Which points to the next issue:

5 - Don't name things that aren't the same thing with the same name (You have a bunch of Vouts that are connected, then some that aren't).

6 - There are many vias and jumpers that can obviously be removed. This might not be the issue but more direct paths will minimize the ratsnest and avoid mistakes. And help find manufacturing issues when they happen.

7 - Please study how schematics and symbols are commonly drawn and organized. It will for one, avoid mistakes, and if they happen, make it a lot easier to collaborate and debug. It is very difficult to get people to help you if they have to decipher your particular schematic language.

[image]

Comment: Got it, thank you. Will redesign the schematic and post as a separate thread.

Comment: @Arian Don't post a new thread. Edit your initial post when you have a real schematic

Comment: Also, I'm surprised nobody posted this yet. One of the community members here, Olin Lanthrop, made a very detailed post about how to draw readable schematics. Have a read: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/28255/41856

Comment: @DerStrom8 got it, thank you!

Comment: @DerStrom8 I hope all is well. I've finally finished the new schematic following design guidelines, but can't post all of the component datasheet links as well as the schematic pictures due to my reputation-limitation. What would you suggest I could do? Thank you again.

Comment: @DerStrom8 I found a workaround!